# android / java get now()-27 second time

Tags: java, android, date, time

```
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int hnow=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        String hour=Integer.toString(hnow);
        String min=Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

this is my code. i get the now time. i d like to get the now()-27 sec (hour, minute, second)

how i can do that?

Comment: Not sure about andriod, but how about `new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 27000);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a negative value is possible, instead of setting a value.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 

calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, -27);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it using the [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class that ships with j2se.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) - 27);

String hour = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
String min = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
String sec = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

As you can see, it's rather tedious. Many people opt to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead of these classes.

Comment: I would consider a lot of date/time operations to be tedious with the JDK and recommend Joda time instead... but I would hardly call this particular exercise tedious.

Comment: @RD: The constants feel yucky, especially on line 2. I suppose that line could have been broken up into 2 lines, but that would make it a little more tedious.

Comment: I agree :)  You can always use Calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, -27) for something a bit cleaner.

Comment: @RD: Good idea. That's certainly cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

i use Clander class my way to do it here is my code to get date and time

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String date = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-"+ c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+ "-"+ c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) ;
String time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+ ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library…

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().minusSeconds( 27 );
```

With a specific time zone rather than default…

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) ).minusSeconds( 27 );
```

To convert to a java.util.Date instance…

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```